# The number of facets of an affine image

Tags: geometry, discrete-mathematics, convex-analysis, computational-geometry, polyhedra

I have a full dimensional polyhedron $P_1 \subseteq \mathbb{R}^d.$  Now i define another polyhedron as follows:

$$P_2 = AP_1 \oplus B$$ with $A \in \mathbb{R}^{(d-1) \times d}, \,\, B \in \mathbb{R}^{d-1}.$

I wonder if one can say something about the number of facets of $P_1$ and $P_2,$  denoted as $\mathcal{H}(P_1)$ and $\mathcal{H}(P_2),$ e.g.

$$\mathcal{H}(P_1) \geq \mathcal{H}(P_2).$$

Sincerely.

Comment: What do you mean by "supporting halfspace"? The number of facets?

Comment: Yeah, sorry for this confusion.